# Trying to use multi-rake with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use this library here: [multi-rake](https://github.com/vgrabovets/multi_rake)

However, as stated in the docs, we have to run this before installing `multi-rake`:

```
CFLAGS="-Wno-narrowing" pip install cld2-cffi
```

So I cannot simply put `cld2-cffi` and `multi-rake` in `requirements.txt` because `cld2-cffi` needs to be installed like this beforehand. How could I overcome this problem?

Comment: If you want to use any executables in your function, they have to be deployed with the function.  You can't preinstall anything on the server instances that runs your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation you have to package as local dependencies.

> You can also package and deploy dependencies alongside your function.
>   This approach is useful if your dependency is not available via the
>   pip package manager or if your Cloud Functions environment's internet
>   access is restricted. For example, you might use a directory structure
>   such as the following:
>
> You can then use code as usual from the included local dependency,
>   localpackage. You can use this approach to bundle any Python packages
>   with your deployment.
>
> Note: You can still use a requirements.txt file to specify additional
>   dependencies you haven't packaged alongside your function.

[Specifying dependencies in Python](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python)

Comment: I know I can do this, however, I don't know how `multi-rake` uses this dependency, so I don't know in where directory should I put it.

Comment: By specifying the CFLAGS value before installing the cld2-cffi dependencies, is specifying additional switches to be passed to the compiler. This step is not possible to achieve in CF. This might be an issue that the people who make multi_rake should address so that their library could be pip installed easily.